# If error happens while creating VM on Azure, where would I find the error log

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have tried creating Windows VM on Azure and it has been few hours and I do not see any VM created. I tried this couple of time. I am using my free subscription account and I am unsuccessful so far in creating a VM for Windows Server 2016 Datacenter image from Azure Marketplace.

So where would I go to check for any audit error log for creating VM on Azure?

Answer (score -1):

enter the resource group where you tried to create the VM and then click on Deployments. There you should see a list of events, one of them should have a red icon. Check if that is the event of VM creation. It will show you the error. Most of the time this problem occurs when you exceed the cores quota or you're trying to create a VM on a region not allowed by your subscription.

Hope it helps.

Regards,